# Conflict of app name in Django with old app name

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am sort of new to Django so I'm using the tutorial on the offical website [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/)

So I created an environment, installed django 2.0.2 and any other packages I needed. Then I opened a terminal and created my polls app with `python manage.py startapp polls`. As I progressed, I decided I wanted to do some things differently and as I'd not really progressed very far, I just deleted my project files and started fresh.

However, on the second pass through when I tried creating my polls app, I get an error that "'polls' conflicts with the name of an existing Python module and cannot be used as an app name."

I have tried deleting the environment and creating a new one but that doesn't work. I tried starting a brand new project, that doesn't work either. There was no problem creating the app the first time so I'm guessing that it is still located somewhere. Is there a method for completely removing apps in django 2.0.2? All the resources I've seen are for earlier versions.

Comment: You don't need to delete virtual env, you have to check django project name and django app name both should be diffrent name

Comment: They are different names... It doesn't matter what I call the project. I can't make a 'polls' app anymore after I made the first one. If I delete the project, I should be able to reuse the name.

Answer (score 4):

May be it will help full for you:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I solved it in this way
it means you have an existing app name in ur directory
if not visible on ur directory close and reopen the editer the you will get it.